# Showing sums for stacked bar Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

I have been trying to sum the columns, but also show the the data between the columns.

I've been looking for documentation but haven't found it. I do not know if it is the correct place where I ask the question

Used the option `dataLabels`.

```
 dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          formatter: function (val) {
            return val + "%";
          },
          offsetY: -20,
          style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            colors: ["#304758"]
          }
        },
```

```js
var options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'PRODUCT A',
    data: [44, 55, 41, 67, 22, 43]
  }, {
    name: 'PRODUCT B',
    data: [13, 23, 20, 8, 13, 27]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350,
    stacked: true,
    toolbar: {
      show: true
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 480,
    options: {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
        offsetX: -10,
        offsetY: 0
      }
    }
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: false,
      borderRadius: 10
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ['01/01/2011 GMT', '01/02/2011 GMT', '01/03/2011 GMT', '01/04/2011 GMT',
      '01/05/2011 GMT', '01/06/2011 GMT'
    ],
  },
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    offsetY: 40
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

However, this just shows the sum of each column.

Comment: I believe [this is what you are looking for](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/754). The developer merged it on Sept 8 but I cannot see it in any release yet.

Comment: The feature is yet to be released. The new version 3.36.0 will have this feature.